# alternative to JasperManager.loadXmlDesign() in Jasperreports 5.5.0?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Does anybody know alternative possibility of `JasperManager.loadXmlDesign()` in Jasperreport 5.5.0 ?

I want to replace following because i move to Jasperreports API 5.5.0:

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JasperManager.loadXmlDesign("BasicReport.xml");
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to load (and compile) a design stored in `.jrxml` file, then you should use `JasperCompileManager.compileReport(String)`. It does both steps you mentioned at a time and returns `JasperReport` directly.

EDIT: If you wish to obtain `JasperDesign` you can load it using `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load()` method.

Comment: thanks for your correction. yes i means `.jrxml` but i need to have both of them `JasperDesign jasperDesign` and `JasperReport jasperReport`